# Selectize is inserting a ? character in data-value attribute

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, selectize.js

I am using selectize.js to build a dropdown list of all cities in Belgium.

```
var cityselect = $('.city-select');
    if (cityselect.length) {
        $('.city-select').selectize({
            create: false,
            sortField: {
                field: 'text',
                direction: 'asc'
            },
            dropdownParent: 'body',
            plugins: ['remove_button']
        });
    }
```

I create the selectize field as following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="city"><?=lang("register_volunteer_select_city_or_commune")?></label>
    <select id="city" class="city-select" name="city" autocomplete="new-password" required data-validation-required-message="<?=lang("register_volunteer_select_city_or_commune_validation")?>">
        <option value="" selected><?=lang("register_volunteer_select_city_or_commune")?></option>
        <?php
        foreach ($citiesbe as $city) {
            if ($this->currentLanguage == 'fr') {
                $cityName = $city->name_fr;
            } else {
                $cityName = $city->name_nl;
            }
            $key = strtolower($cityName) . "," . $city->zip_code;
            echo "<option value=\"$key\"> $cityName ($city->zip_code)</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <div class="help-block font-small-3"></div>
</div>
```

In Belgium, there are a lot of cities with French names (eg: Léglise) that contain a special character (é, è, ç, ...) etc. 
The variable $citiesbe, comes from my table "cities_be", and the entry for Léglise looks like this:

```
+--------------+----------+---------+---------+--------+-------+
| cities_be_id | zip_code | name_nl | name_fr |  lat   |  lng  |
+--------------+----------+---------+---------+--------+-------+
|         1786 |     6860 | Léglise | Léglise | 49,784 | 5,538 |
+--------------+----------+---------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Then in my selectize, I can select Léglise and it looks great, but when I inspect the element, I will notice that the data-value is set to the following value:

```
<div data-value="l�glise,6860" class="item"> Léglise (6860)</div>
```

Because it inserts special characters (é in this example) as a ? it passes this through the POST variables as a ? and thus it generates a lot of errors.

How do I go about this problem?

I have set my database charset & collation to utf8mb4 , the connection with database via PHP is also set to utf8mb4, and my document contains a charset line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

I'm completely running out of idea's here on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using mb_strtolower()?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php

```
$b = mb_strtolower($a);
echo $b;
```

PHP5 is not UTF-8 compatible, doesn't work on multi-byte characters, so you still need to resort to the mb extension.